# add css property if element is displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, menu

I have a menu that is shown on certain pages (using wordpress here). To make sure this menu doesn't overlap the content I've added a padding to the content wrap. What I now need is for this padding to only be in effect on pages displaying the menu element (#toc_container).

Is this possible using css or using some other trick?

Answer (score 2):

Quick JS-solution:

**Vanilla**

```
var menu = document.getElementById("toc_container");
var body = document.body;
if (menu !== null) {
    body.style.paddingTop = menu.clientHeight + "px";
}
```

**jQuery**

```
var $menu = $("#toc_container");
var $body = $("body");
if ($menu.length > 0) {
    $body.css('padding-top', $menu.outerHeight(true));
}
```

This checks for menu's existence and adds a padding equal to the menu's height if so.

Answer (score 0):

Got help from a friend and added the following. Worked as a charm :)

```
if (document.getElementById("toc_container"))
{
    sheet = document.styleSheets[0];
    if (sheet.insertRule) sheet.insertRule(".x-container {padding-right: 250px}", sheet.cssRules.length);
    else  if (sheet.addRule) sheet.addRule(".x-container",  "padding-right: 250px");
};
```